# JavaScript Function keeps returning undefined after showing the output

Tags: javascript, function

The code answers true or false but after it keeps saying undefined e.g trueundefined. What could i have done wrong?

```
function gamble(){
   let prob = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
   let prize = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
 let pay = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
  let probPrize = prob * prize;
if (probPrize > pay){
  document.write('True');

}else{
  document.write('False');
}

};

document.write(gamble());
```

Comment: gamble() doest not return anything so you can't use it on document.write method

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the function, so it's undefined.

Replace `document.write('True')` with `return 'True'` and `document.write('False')` with `return 'False'`

Comment: or just replace `document.write(gamble());` with `gamble()` :D

Answer (score 0):

because your function `gamble` doesn't return any value

replace your code to this :

```
function gamble(){
   let prob = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
   let prize = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
   let pay = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'));
   let probPrize = prob * prize;
   if (probPrize > pay){
    return 'True';
   }else{
    return 'False';
   }
};
document.write(gamble());
```